UDP traffic DNAT doesn't return as expected
I'm looking for a solution with the following situation.
There is server1 with public interface eth0 and IP 33.33.33.33 and GRE interface 10.10.10.1, GRE tunnel point to second server2 with public interface 44.44.44.44 and GRE interface 10.10.10.2.
server1 configuration:
ip_wan: 33.33.33.33
ip_gre: 10.10.10.1
ip tunnel add gre1 mode gre local 33.33.33.33 remote 44.44.44.44 ttl 255
ip addr add 10.10.10.1/30 dev gre1
ip link set gre1 up
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -s 10.10.10.0/30 -o gre+ -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.10.1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 33.33.33.33 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.2
iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.10.10.2 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.10.10.2 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i gre+ -j ACCEPT
... all rules to allow traffic

server2 configuration:
ip_wan: 44.44.44.44
ip_gre: 10.10.10.2
ip tunnel add gre1 mode gre local 44.44.44.44 remote 33.33.33.33 ttl 255
ip addr add 10.10.10.2/30 dev gre1
ip link set gre1 up
ip route add default via 10.10.10.1 dev gre1 table GREP1
.... all rules to allow traffic

TCP traffic coming to server1 is forwarded to server2 and return back and is translated to server1 public IP. UDP traffic coming to server1 is forwarded to server2 and go through public IP on server2 instead of return back.
I tried a lot of examples, but nothing work as needed. Any pointers which could move me further.

Hello, it's java app, but meanwhile I found a solution - I have to add MASQUERADE to gre1 interface on server1 and everything start working as expected. I checked tcpdump on both servers and it looks like without it the packets loop on 10.10.10.2 in infinite loop.  Maybe this will help someone looking for the same solution. Thank you for your comment.

One guideline if you use DNAT on the PREROUTING chain is that you usually have SNAT on the POSTROUTING chain, and they need to apply to the same packets. Your SNAT is outright wrong because they apply to different packets.
Let's check the DNAT first:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 33.33.33.33 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.2

This is correct. Packets coming from the Internet destined to the router's public IP address gets NAT-ed so it will be delivered to 10.10.10.2.
However, the SNAT:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/30 ! -o gre+ -j SNAT --to-source 33.33.33.33

is wrong. Notably because here the -o gre part is negated. Maybe you want to negate the source address instead?
Also, when doing SNAT, you will want to change the source to the address on the router that's facing the "next hop".
So a corrected rule will be:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -s 10.10.10.0/30 -o gre+ -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.10.1

Breaking this down:

Source (which hasn't been changed up to now) is NOT in 10.10.10.0/30
Output interface is "gre+" (that is, any interface whose name begin with "gre")
Change the packet's Source IP to 10.10.10.1, which is the router's GRE-facing address

As you have discovered, using MASQUERADE also works because MASQUERADE is basically SNAT, but automatically detecting the outgoing IP address, in case it's a dynamic IP address. But there's a catch: If the GRE tunnel glitches, all NAT tracking will be flushed. Read more about this
If the outgoing interface's address is static, especially in a tunnel like in your scenario, it is strongly suggested to use SNAT instead.

Great ! You are right, I will edit my text, so it will be right, but really good point man from you ;)
